# why is there a "never use non-literal type" rule in constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Take the following legal code:

```
bool bar();

template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
  if (t>0) {
    return true;
  }
  return bar();
}


int main() {
  //constexpr bool cb1 = foo(-1); // error as expected  because it would attempt to call bar()
  constexpr bool cb2 = foo(1); // ok
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/UWt_3A

So, as long as we don't hit a non-constexpr code-path in a compile time evaluation context our constexpr is well formed. Neat!

However, if I apply the same practical notion, but happen to include a non-literal type in a conditional code-path, such as `std::string`, then the standard says no-no:

```
#include <string>

bool bar(std::string);

template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
  if (t>0) {
    return true;
  }
  std::string s = "abc";
  return bar(s);
}


int main() {
  //constexpr bool cb1 = foo(-1); // error as expected
  constexpr bool cb2 = foo(1); // this is also an error now :(
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/iHThCq

What is the rationale behind this? Why is using std::string illegal at all cost even though it never actually gets constructed (or destroyed)?

Bonus question: why is the following legal then: https://godbolt.org/z/L3np-u  (slight variation on above, without defining std::string) ?!

Comment: Yeah, the rule indeed exists, [even in the latest standard draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#3.5.3). It does seem a bit draconic to me too. Following this with great curiosity.

Comment: fwiw, I don't think this is a fundamental limitation (maybe compilers have difficulty with checking if the non-literal variable needs to be instantiated). It seems like this constraint could be removed.

Comment: Not draconian at all, it's pretty easy to fix, wrap your non-literal variable in a lambda and call it.

Comment: bar is a function definition here.

Comment: BTW: std::string becomes a literal type in C++20 - but that does not answer the question

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9E49zE msvc doesn't seem to have a problem, so maybe that is implementation specific? Perhaps the standard doesnt specify to check only the path followed and ignore others.

Comment: The standard does say that it may not contain a non-literal _variable_ , so maybe the variable declaration is triggering the error regardless if it is encountered in execution path.

Comment: There _is_ a way to make it compile under GCC if you make the if check itself constexpr, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But it does not work with clang: see here https://godbolt.org/z/1cKa13

Comment: I would guess it has some "historic" reason. You could ask, why is "goto" not allowed, too. It would be possible at compile time. But that would cause additional implementation overhead... In c++11 only a single return was allowed...

Comment: @Bernd they seem to have taken the principle that it's easy to make illegal things legal, but hard to make legal things illegal, so they were very conservative at the beginning

Answer (score 4):

I'm just guessing here, but can it be because being `std::string s = "abc"` an automatic variable and allocated in the stack at function begin (even if not yet constructed) breaks the `constexpr` rules?

If I change the code to:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

bool bar(std::string);

template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //std::string ss = "abc"s;
        return bar("abc"s);
    }
    return false;
}
```

as there is no need to allocate anything it compiles.

I explain my reasoning (and response to comments) here, as I need more space than in a comment.

As @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica says, "guessing is a bad basis for answering questions".

Absolutely yes. That's why I begin saying just that: I'm guessing. And that have a reason.

I don't like to guess normally but I found this interesting and want to throw a thought to see if someone says I'm wrong (something I'm pretty ready to accept.)

But going to the point, literal type variables are normally stored at some read only memory data segment (unless they are numbers, those can be translated directly to ASM MOV/... instructions), not at stack.

If declared automatic (storing at stack):

> Storage duration
>
> All objects in a program have one of the following storage durations:
>
> automatic storage duration. The storage for the object is *allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block* and deallocated at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared static, extern or thread_local.

(Emphasis mine.)

So, even if declared after the `if`, the storage is allocated and should be deallocated in any case (in the example shown by OP.)

In fact, if done like this:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    }
    const std::string ss = "abc"s;
    return bar(ss);
}
```

the error is:

```
main.cc:15:16: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> std::literals::string_literals::operator""s(const char*, std::size_t)’
```

why? *I guess* because, being automatic, "the storage for the object is *allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block*" (beginning of the function) no matter the execution code path.

Moreover, if you declare it `constexpr`, it introduces the destructor:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    }
    constexpr std::string ss = "abc"s;
    return bar(ss);
}
```

error:

```
main.cc:19:32: error: temporary of non-literal type ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} in a constant expression
     constexpr std::string ss = "abc"s;
                                ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/string:52,
                 from main.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:77:11: note: ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ is not literal because:
     class basic_string
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:77:11: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ has a non-trivial destructor
main.cc: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool foo(T) [with T = int]’:
main.cc:25:29:   required from here
main.cc:19:27: error: the type ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘ss’ is not literal
     constexpr std::string ss = "abc"s;
```

I think the key is: `‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ has a non-trivial destructor`.

so the theoretical call to the destructor is taken in account before the execution code path.

Why?

Because "the storage for the object is *allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block*".

The following:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    }
    return bar("abc"s);
}
```

creates a temporary:

```
main.cc:19:15: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘bool bar(std::__cxx11::string)’
     return bar("abc"s);
```

but

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return bar("abc"s);
    }
    return false;
}
```

creates the temporary *only* if the execution path goes to the `else` (which is not the case.)

As said, this is a *guess*, but I think a *based* guess, not just a blind try.

Again, I'm convinced this depends on compiler implementation. I'm by no means a C++ standard expert, but I haven't been able to find this explicit case in any document.

I've run the program in `gdb` to see if it enters in the `foo` function:

```
bool bar(std::string);

template <class T>
constexpr bool foo(T t) {
    if (t>0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //std::string ss = "abc"s;
        return bar("abc"s);
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    //constexpr bool cb1 = foo(-1); // error as expected
    constexpr bool cb2 = foo(1); // this is also an error now :(

    cout << "Bool: " << cb2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

it links without `bar` being defined so...

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -g main.cc -o main --std=gnu++2a -Wpedantic && time ./main
Bool: 1

real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,002s
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ gdb ./main
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./main...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x117d: file main.cc, line 27.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/manuel/projects/main 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cc:27
27      constexpr bool cb2 = foo(1); // this is also an error now :(
(gdb) s
29      cout << "Bool: " << cb2 << endl;
(gdb) s
Bool: 1
31      return 0;
(gdb) s
32  }
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 18799] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Comment: Guessing is a bad basis for answering questions. A literal type variable will also be on "the stack" by your reasoning. But such a variable is allowed. So how can "the stack" possibly be the explanation?

Comment: Why did you remove the else block? The same error you get happens when the string variable is in that block. I guess you had to so that your explanation will look plausible. Storage duration has nothing to do with it.

Comment: while a reasonable argument, i didn't accept this because the proof isn't solid:  `else {        return bar("abc"s); }`  compiles just fine without the `else` - i.e. no nested scope needed. See my "why is the following legal then" example at the end of my original question.

Comment: @Nick there is no allocation for the string if t>0, so no constructor, destructor or even the function call, so no memory reservation. If you change that to: `std::string a ("abc");  return bar(a);` there will be allocation (even if no function call) and compilation will fail.

Comment: it behaves precisely the same way with or without `else`, with or without a local named variable in any combination. your example after "Why?" with `bar("abc")` in function scope does *not* fail to compile. i don't know which compiler you got this from. see, again, my very last godbolt link.

Answer (score 1):

Because your second code violates the following rule:

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> > - its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or a compound-statement that **does not contain**
> >
> > > - a **definition of a variable of non-literal type** or of static or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is performed.

Since in your second code, you defined a variable like `std::string s = "abc";`, thereof, the type `std::string` is a non-literal type, hence that violates the rule I cited. So, your second code is ill-formed.

#### UPDATE:

why the rule is necessary to exist? because the following rule:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. In any constexpr variable declaration, the **full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression**.

The full-expression of the initialization include the invocation of destructor, due to this rule:

> A full-expression is
>
> > - an invocation of a destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object **other than a temporary object**, or

Because `std::string s = "abc";` is a variable with automatic duration storage, It's not a temporary object, hence the invocation of its destructor be included within the full-expression of the initialization. Because the destructor of non-literal type wouldn't be a constexpr function, So this is why the rule is necessary.

Comment: That's the premise of the question. The question is *why* that rule exists :)

Comment: The OP is aware. As they say *"then the standard says no-no"*. The question is **why** is the  rule there, even when nothing about that `std::string` is evaluated.

Comment: @Quentin I don't know what you mean? as long as you defined a variable of non-literal type, It will violate the rule, hence your code will result in ill-formed regardless of whether the expression would be evaluated or not.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica see this [outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/GxKTcf), clang will be ok. why? because clang obey the rule what the standard specified. I think.

Comment: You did not understand the question. Plain and simple.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have understood and update my answers.

Comment: Nah, I don't buy it. The object in question doesn't even start its lifetime.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the object starts its lifetime at the beginning of the enclosing scope, so yes, it begins to exist at function start. The point is: one compiler takes this first, and the other takes the code execution path first. In each case the result is different. If you take the execution path first, the object doesn't exists. The unknown is: do the standard explicitly tell which one goes first?

Comment: @Manuel - No, it doesn't. An object's lifetime starts when its initialization is complete. That's the normative defintion.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, you are right. Lifetime begins when both, storage and initialization are complete. The storage begins at block scope and initialization at object declaration. So I expressed my thoughts wrongly. I was trying to say that may be `g++` takes in account the non-trivial destructor just because it allocated space for the object, even if it wasn't initialized.